# How to get system location zipcode using jquery or python

Tags: jquery, python-2.7

I need to display system location zipcode. I am done this using following link

http://ip-api.com/json

But it is not working in live site because of http.
I am getting following errors

"Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.xom' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://ip-api.com/json/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

And

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ip-api.com/json/. Failed to start loading."

So Can any one suggest me another alternatives with https or any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little googling reveals this: https://freegeoip.net/json/ which returns this on my machine:

> {"ip":"24.158.153.252","country_code":"US","country_name":"United States","region_code":"TN","region_name":"Tennessee","city":"McMinnville","zip_code":"37110","time_zone":"America/Chicago","latitude":35.6525,"longitude":-85.7284,"metro_code":659}

It isn't quite as accurate as the one you're using (I live about 20 miles from McMinnville, which I believe is where the nearest hub of my ISP is) but it does allow use of the SSL for free.  Alternatively, you can use the one you're using with SSL if you pay €15 a month: terms are [here](https://signup.ip-api.com/).  Finally, you can consider writing something of your own using the Google Geolocation API, the Mozilla Geolocation API, or some such.